# Rename column with quotation mark on start of its name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table with unknown column's names from import and I'm trying to rename its. For example:

```
DECLARE @Col1 nvarchar(128);

SELECT @Col1 = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = mytable and ordinal_position = 1;

DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(255);
SET @ColName = '[mytable.' + @Col1 + ']';
sp_RENAME @ColName, '[MyColumn]', 'COLUMN';
```

It doesn't work when `@Col1` starts from quotation mark like `"RudeColumName` and returns: `Incorrect syntax near 'sp_RENAME'.` Also rename by using `ALTER TABLE` doesn't work and returns syntax error.

How could I rename this column?

Answer (score 1):

`QUOTENAME()` is the right function to use.  This is how you would use it:

```
DECLARE @Col1 nvarchar(128);

SELECT @Col1 = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = mytable and ordinal_position = 1;

DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(255);
SET @ColName = QUOTENAME('mytable') + '.' + QUOTENAME(@Col1);

sp_RENAME @ColName, '[MyColumn]', 'COLUMN';
```

Note:  it is used separately for the table name and the column name.

Of course, you might also need `QUOTENAME()` around the new name as well.  On the other hand, simply don't use new column names that require quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @Col1 nvarchar(128);

SELECT @Col1 = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = mytable and ordinal_position = 1;

DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(255);
SET @ColName = '[mytable.''' + @Col1 + ']';
sp_RENAME @ColName, '[MyColumn]', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same syntax error again.

Maybe I need to add result of `PRINT @Col1`:

My code: `[mytable."RudeColumName]`
yours: `[mytable.'"RudeColumName]`
but also it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about to use [**QUOTENAME**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) instead of brackets `[]`?

```
DECLARE @Col1 nvarchar(128);

SELECT @Col1 = COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = mytable and ordinal_position = 1;

DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(255);
SET @ColName = QUOTENAME('mytable.' + @Col1);
sp_RENAME @ColName, '[MyColumn]', 'COLUMN';
```